# Customized Macro toolbar not working on another computer

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a few macro codes (in Personal) and created a customized interface by adding a "Macro's" groups on Quick Access Toolbar
[image]

I want the same interface on other computers, for this I saved the 'Personal' Wb and exported the customized interface below. On the other computer, 'Personal' WB was saved in the same directory i.e. ..../XLSTART and imported the said interface
On the other computer, no problem is faced in the above process, however when I run the code through 'Macro's' ribbon the following error appears
[image]

The code runs successfully, If I run it through Visual Basic editor (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and then run the code by <kbd>F5</kbd>) but does not run through the ribbon.
I have enabled macros on the other computer.

Comment: Were the user names also identical? They are part of the full path and have to match as well.

Comment: You may want to consider making it an Add-In instead if you plan on distributing it to others.

Comment: How to make it as an add-in?

Comment: Then assuming you are in a networked environment, save the file to a network location so it has a common path... just wanted to make sure you didn't miss that part of any tutorial you read about it.